# Killing the activity when user clicks the home button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Okey, this is weird.
I have two activities (well, more than two, but they don't matter) - AppActivity and PopupActivity. AppActivity is my main application activity and it contains my app's settings. PopupActivity is a dialog that gets opened when user clicks the button in the notification (it's a RemoteViews notification). Well, it works. Works great. But only if user closed the AppActivity by clicking the *back* button. If they clicked *home*, PopupActivity opens after a few seconds after clicking the button. Same thing happens when user closes the PopupActivity with a home button. Clicking the button in the notification doesn't open the PopupActivity instantly, but it takes a few seconds to kill the previous activity that still exists somewhere in the background.

I've tried calling finish() in the onStop and onPause methods, but it doesn't fix my problem.

**Edit:** Here's the code I have:

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="cc.lupine.quicksocial.AppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:noHistory="true" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" 
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
        android:showOnLockScreen="false" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth" 
        android:name="cc.lupine.quicksocial.PopupActivity" 
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity="" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="cc.lupine.quicksocial.ShareService"></service>
```

ShareService.java (just a function that gets called when user clicks a button in the notification):

```
public static void startSharing(Context ctx, int n) {
    Log.d("sn", "startsharing called in shareservice");
    if(n == 1 || n == 2)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(ThisApplication.getAppContext(), PopupActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("shareType", n);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|
                  Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND|
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(i);
    } else if(n == 3) {
        // doesn't matter for now
    }
}
```

PopupActivity.java (fragments):

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity implements OnDataPass {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("sn", "oncreate called in popupactivity");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instanceOfPopupActivity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);

        ShareFragment sfrag = new ShareFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        try {
            //doesn't matter
        } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); finish(); }
        sfrag.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contFragment, sfrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); 

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.d("sn", "onpause called in popupactivity");
        finish();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.d("sn", "onstop called in popupactivity");
        super.onStop();
    } 
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.d("sn", "ondestroy called in popupactivity");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

And if I open the popup for the first time:

```
05-26 14:37:14.149: D/sn(7218): startsharing called in shareservice
05-26 14:37:14.179: D/sn(7218): oncreate called in popupactivity
```

But when I close the popup with a home button and try to open it again:

```
05-26 14:38:11.620: D/sn(7218): startsharing called in shareservice
05-26 14:38:14.103: D/sn(7218): oncreate called in popupactivity
```

It takes a lot of time for onCreate to be called. And now, what's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are focusing on the wrong problem (killing the activity) instead of focusing on the real problem (10 seconds to start it again).

First you need to understand WHY it is taking 10 seconds to open it if you exited the other acitivty with the home key!

If you posted more details (with source code) it would have been easier to understand and help you!

Comment: Edited to include the source code. Now it should be more clear!

Answer (score 0):

call finish() when you want to close app. Call finish() on both activities and watch out popup window has to be focusable to handle click.

Comment: I've tried calling finish() in both onPause and onStop, in AppActivity, PopupActivity and in both. onPause/onStop gets triggered every time the home button is clicked, finish() gets called, but it still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: System.err.println("HI!"); put it in method detecting HOME button click, anw watch log cat. I think that you are not detecting it properly. finish closes application if called, there is no way it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't detect home button click. It would be too tricky and wouldn't cover the action when users switches to any other app using the multitasking menu. That's why I call `finish()` in onPause or onStop - I want to destroy the activity every time it leaves the foreground.

Comment: I don't know why would you like to kill your app as soon as it leaves foreground. I have done similar stuff, but I have put finish  to be called as event on back button. Have you called super.onPause before finish()? Cause maybe app goes to background before finish is called.

Comment: I've troed calling `finish()` before and after super, but it doesn't change anything. I need to kill the activity because if it isn't killed, it takes about 10 seconds to start it again after users clicks the notification button. One thing I noticed is that a back button triggers onPause, then onStop and then onDestroy, while a home button triggers only the first two.